# cannot create longtable

Tags: longtable

could you please help me with the following matter? I am trying to create a long table using the `longtable` environment. But I keep getting errors. Thank you. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, draft, titlepage]{article}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.05in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.04in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.6 in}
\setlength{\textheight}{600pt} \setlength{\topmargin}{0 in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0 in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5 cm}
\newcommand {\st}{\setlength{\baselineskip}{24pt}}
\newcommand{\fn}{\footnote}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvips]{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow, afterpage, bigstrut}
\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l}
\caption{Results from OLS Estimation}
\begin{small}
\hline
\hline
          & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Males} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Females} \\
\hline
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{OLS-NGive} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{OLS-GGive} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{OLS-GRec} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{OLS-NGive} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{OLS-GGive} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{OLS-GRec} \\

\hline
\endfirsthead

\hline \multicolumn{7}{|r|}{{\tablename} \thetable{} -- Continued} \\ \hline
          & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Males} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Females} \\
\hline
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{OLS-NGive} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{OLS-GGive} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{OLS-GRec} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{OLS-NGive} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{OLS-GGive} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{OLS-GRec} \\

\hline
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{7}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot

    Log wage & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.2754**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.1301*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.1309**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.3629**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.2700**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0815+} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0814)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0613)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0494)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0803)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0625)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0473)} \\
    Age   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0128} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0589} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0432} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0879} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0226} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0691} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0880)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0740)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0473)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0812)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0600)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0520)} \\
    Age sq & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0001} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0004} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0005} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0007} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0002} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0005} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0008)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0006)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0004)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0007)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0005)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0005)} \\
    Educ  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0174} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0721} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.1064**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.1381} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.2056*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0770**} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0609)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0543)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0245)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0902)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0848)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0258)} \\
    Educ sq & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0003} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0051*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0055**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0051} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0095**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0047**} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0026)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0022)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0013)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0036)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0032)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0013)} \\
    Non-labor inc & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0027*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0024*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0003} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0010} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0013+} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0002} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0012)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0010)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0005)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0008)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0007)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0004)} \\
    HH wealth & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0079} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0160*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0077} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0022} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0004} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0012} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0093)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0068)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0050)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0043)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0038)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0019)} \\
    Nwhite & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.9998**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.7522**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.2394**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.6197**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.4897**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.1332*} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.1271)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.1149)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0470)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.1142)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0968)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0572)} \\
    Hisp  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.6440**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.4753**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.1572**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.6450**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.6302**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0371} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.1728)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.1607)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0559)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.1904)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.1719)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0701)} \\
    Married & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.3104*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.3796**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0801} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.2232*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0784} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.3247**} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.1472)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.1296)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0853)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.1107)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0858)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0662)} \\
    Poor health & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0069} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0406} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0520} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0710} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0845} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.1645**} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.1004)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0801)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0576)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.1052)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0844)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0590)} \\
    Children (0-5) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.1143} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0376} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0835} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0154} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0310} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0397} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.1293)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0927)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0825)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.1083)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0919)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0561)} \\
    Children (6-18) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.1533*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0320} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.1166**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.1228+} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0113} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.1015*} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0675)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0513)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0400)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0652)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0487)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0407)} \\
    N of own sis & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0388} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0311} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0098} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0632*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0008} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0510**} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0281)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0221)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0152)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0250)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0208)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0121)} \\
    N of own bro & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0514+} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0228} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0270+} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0099} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0128} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0206} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0268)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0223)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0138)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0271)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0224)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0138)} \\
    N of spouse sis & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0115} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0176} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0275*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0105} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0042} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0197} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0270)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0221)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0136)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0277)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0226)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0146)} \\
    N of spouse bro & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0052} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0026} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0002} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0247} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0168} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0091} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0311)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0252)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0159)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0292)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0246)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0141)} \\
    N of parents & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.2854**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.3605**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0725*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.2085**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.2918**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0849*} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0621)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0469)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0367)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0625)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0466)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0367)} \\
    Mothers/parents & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.2108+} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.2918**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0499} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.2833*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.3428**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0369} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.1190)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0862)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0772)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.1119)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0799)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0753)} \\
    Parents' age & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0137*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0052} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0076*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0088} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0022} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0096*} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0067)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0056)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0036)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0068)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0055)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0038)} \\
    Parents' educ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0619**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0140} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0437**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0506**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0064} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0444**} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0168)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0139)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0080)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0158)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0128)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0083)} \\
    At least one parent &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  \\
    single & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.2178*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.3229**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.1104+} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.1486+} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.2837**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.1480**} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0945)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0706)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0575)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0873)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0668)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0524)} \\
    needs care & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0447} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0174} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0586} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0251} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0068} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0297} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0892)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0735)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0459)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0857)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0694)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0466)} \\
    cannot be & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0740} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.1054} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0193} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0068} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0029} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0188} \\
    left alone & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0981)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0797)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0511)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0913)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0733)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0499)} \\
    homeowner & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0436} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0117} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0492} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0185} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0415} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0276} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0957)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0814)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0448)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0897)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0745)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0461)} \\
    poorer & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.8224**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.7197**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.1096*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.8435**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.6969**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.1552**} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0828)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0671)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0434)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0798)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0668)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0397)} \\
    richer & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.9860**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.4509**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.5021**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.0081**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.4896**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.4862**} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0851)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0636)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0525)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0805)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0590)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0495)} \\
\hline
    Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{11,387} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{11,387} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{11,387} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{13,275} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{13,275} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{13,275} \\
    R-squared & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0956} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0875} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0570} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0929} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0819} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0555} \\
\hline
\hline
\end{small}
\label{tab:OLSresults}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Would you be able to reduce your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and describe a little bit more precisely which errors you get? It would make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Not sure you really need to use multicolumn in every data cell. If I were you, I would start from a minimal table and added elements 1 by 1. This is how you work in Latex - by small increments, baby steps. Do you really expect someone inspecting your large MWE with repeated similar elements, looking for a bug somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

First... an advise **keep it simple!** if you are adding a single value, don't use `\multicolumn`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, draft, titlepage]{article}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.05in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.04in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.6 in}
\setlength{\textheight}{600pt} \setlength{\topmargin}{0 in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0 in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5 cm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}




\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Males} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Females} \\
  \hline
  & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} \\
  & {OLS-NGive} & {OLS-GGive} & {OLS-GRec} & {OLS-NGive} & {OLS-GGive} & {OLS-GRec} \\
  \hline
  \endfirsthead
  \hline
  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Males} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Females} \\
  \hline
  & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} \\
  & {OLS-NGive} & {OLS-GGive} & {OLS-GRec} & {OLS-NGive} & {OLS-GGive} & {OLS-GRec} \\
  \hline
  \endhead
  \hline \multicolumn{7}{r}{(Continued on next page)} \\ 
  \endfoot    
  \hline 
  \endlastfoot
  Log wage & {0.2754**} & {0.1301*} & {-0.1309**} & {0.3629**} & {0.2700**} & {-0.0815+} \\
  & {(0.0814)} & {(0.0613)} & {(0.0494)} & {(0.0803)} & {(0.0625)} & {(0.0473)} \\
    Age   & {0.0128} & {0.0589} & {0.0432} & {0.0879} & {0.0226} & {-0.0691} \\
    & {(0.0880)} & {(0.0740)} & {(0.0473)} & {(0.0812)} & {(0.0600)} & {(0.0520)} \\
    Age sq & {0.0001} & {-0.0004} & {-0.0005} & {-0.0007} & {-0.0002} & {0.0005} \\
    & {(0.0008)} & {(0.0006)} & {(0.0004)} & {(0.0007)} & {(0.0005)} & {(0.0005)} \\
    Educ  & {0.0174} & {-0.0721} & {-0.1064**} & {-0.1381} & {-0.2056*} & {-0.0770**} \\
    & {(0.0609)} & {(0.0543)} & {(0.0245)} & {(0.0902)} & {(0.0848)} & {(0.0258)} \\
    Educ sq & {0.0003} & {0.0051*} & {0.0055**} & {0.0051} & {0.0095**} & {0.0047**} \\
    & {(0.0026)} & {(0.0022)} & {(0.0013)} & {(0.0036)} & {(0.0032)} & {(0.0013)} \\
    Non-labor inc & {0.0027*} & {0.0024*} & {-0.0003} & {0.0010} & {0.0013+} & {0.0002} \\
    & {(0.0012)} & {(0.0010)} & {(0.0005)} & {(0.0008)} & {(0.0007)} & {(0.0004)} \\
    HH wealth & {0.0079} & {0.0160*} & {0.0077} & {0.0022} & {0.0004} & {-0.0012} \\
    & {(0.0093)} & {(0.0068)} & {(0.0050)} & {(0.0043)} & {(0.0038)} & {(0.0019)} \\
    Nwhite & {0.9998**} & {0.7522**} & {-0.2394**} & {0.6197**} & {0.4897**} & {-0.1332*} \\
    & {(0.1271)} & {(0.1149)} & {(0.0470)} & {(0.1142)} & {(0.0968)} & {(0.0572)} \\
    Hisp  & {0.6440**} & {0.4753**} & {-0.1572**} & {0.6450**} & {0.6302**} & {-0.0371} \\
    & {(0.1728)} & {(0.1607)} & {(0.0559)} & {(0.1904)} & {(0.1719)} & {(0.0701)} \\
    Married & {-0.3104*} & {-0.3796**} & {-0.0801} & {0.2232*} & {-0.0784} & {-0.3247**} \\
    & {(0.1472)} & {(0.1296)} & {(0.0853)} & {(0.1107)} & {(0.0858)} & {(0.0662)} \\
    Poor health & {-0.0069} & {0.0406} & {0.0520} & {-0.0710} & {0.0845} & {0.1645**} \\
    & {(0.1004)} & {(0.0801)} & {(0.0576)} & {(0.1052)} & {(0.0844)} & {(0.0590)} \\
    Children (0-5) & {-0.1143} & {-0.0376} & {0.0835} & {0.0154} & {-0.0310} & {-0.0397} \\
    & {(0.1293)} & {(0.0927)} & {(0.0825)} & {(0.1083)} & {(0.0919)} & {(0.0561)} \\
    Children (6-18) & {-0.1533*} & {-0.0320} & {0.1166**} & {-0.1228+} & {-0.0113} & {0.1015*} \\
    & {(0.0675)} & {(0.0513)} & {(0.0400)} & {(0.0652)} & {(0.0487)} & {(0.0407)} \\
    N of own sis & {-0.0388} & {-0.0311} & {0.0098} & {0.0632*} & {-0.0008} & {-0.0510**} \\
    & {(0.0281)} & {(0.0221)} & {(0.0152)} & {(0.0250)} & {(0.0208)} & {(0.0121)} \\
    N of own bro & {0.0514+} & {0.0228} & {-0.0270+} & {0.0099} & {-0.0128} & {-0.0206} \\
    & {(0.0268)} & {(0.0223)} & {(0.0138)} & {(0.0271)} & {(0.0224)} & {(0.0138)} \\
    N of spouse sis & {0.0115} & {-0.0176} & {-0.0275*} & {-0.0105} & {0.0042} & {0.0197} \\
    & {(0.0270)} & {(0.0221)} & {(0.0136)} & {(0.0277)} & {(0.0226)} & {(0.0146)} \\
    N of spouse bro & {0.0052} & {0.0026} & {0.0002} & {0.0247} & {0.0168} & {-0.0091} \\
    & {(0.0311)} & {(0.0252)} & {(0.0159)} & {(0.0292)} & {(0.0246)} & {(0.0141)} \\
    N of parents & {0.2854**} & {0.3605**} & {0.0725*} & {0.2085**} & {0.2918**} & {0.0849*} \\
    & {(0.0621)} & {(0.0469)} & {(0.0367)} & {(0.0625)} & {(0.0466)} & {(0.0367)} \\
    Mothers/parents & {0.2108+} & {0.2918**} & {0.0499} & {0.2833*} & {0.3428**} & {0.0369} \\
    & {(0.1190)} & {(0.0862)} & {(0.0772)} & {(0.1119)} & {(0.0799)} & {(0.0753)} \\
    Parents' age & {-0.0137*} & {-0.0052} & {0.0076*} & {-0.0088} & {0.0022} & {0.0096*} \\
    & {(0.0067)} & {(0.0056)} & {(0.0036)} & {(0.0068)} & {(0.0055)} & {(0.0038)} \\
    Parents' educ & {-0.0619**} & {-0.0140} & {0.0437**} & {-0.0506**} & {-0.0064} & {0.0444**} \\
    & {(0.0168)} & {(0.0139)} & {(0.0080)} & {(0.0158)} & {(0.0128)} & {(0.0083)} \\
    At least one parent &       & {} &       &       & {} &  \\
    single & {0.2178*} & {0.3229**} & {0.1104+} & {0.1486+} & {0.2837**} & {0.1480**} \\
    & {(0.0945)} & {(0.0706)} & {(0.0575)} & {(0.0873)} & {(0.0668)} & {(0.0524)} \\
    needs care & {0.0447} & {-0.0174} & {-0.0586} & {0.0251} & {0.0068} & {-0.0297} \\
    & {(0.0892)} & {(0.0735)} & {(0.0459)} & {(0.0857)} & {(0.0694)} & {(0.0466)} \\
    cannot be & {0.0740} & {0.1054} & {0.0193} & {-0.0068} & {-0.0029} & {0.0188} \\
    left alone & {(0.0981)} & {(0.0797)} & {(0.0511)} & {(0.0913)} & {(0.0733)} & {(0.0499)} \\
    homeowner & {-0.0436} & {0.0117} & {0.0492} & {0.0185} & {0.0415} & {0.0276} \\
    & {(0.0957)} & {(0.0814)} & {(0.0448)} & {(0.0897)} & {(0.0745)} & {(0.0461)} \\
    poorer & {0.8224**} & {0.7197**} & {-0.1096*} & {0.8435**} & {0.6969**} & {-0.1552**} \\
    & {(0.0828)} & {(0.0671)} & {(0.0434)} & {(0.0798)} & {(0.0668)} & {(0.0397)} \\
    richer & {-0.9860**} & {-0.4509**} & {0.5021**} & {-1.0081**} & {-0.4896**} & {0.4862**} \\
    & {(0.0851)} & {(0.0636)} & {(0.0525)} & {(0.0805)} & {(0.0590)} & {(0.0495)} \\
    \hline
    Observations & {11,387} & {11,387} & {11,387} & {13,275} & {13,275} & {13,275} \\
    R-squared & {0.0956} & {0.0875} & {0.0570} & {0.0929} & {0.0819} & {0.0555}\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I removed the spurious `\multicolumn{1}{#}{ }` and some packages which do not contribute with the example... and your code works almost completely!

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

From the errors I received, you should:
(1) Add to the preamble

```
\usepackage{longtable}
```

(2) Move the `small` environment outside the `longtable`:

```
\begin{small}
\begin{longtable}{...}
...
\end{longtable}
\end{small}
```

(3) Follow the caption with `\\` (and cancel the `small` with `\normalsize`):

```
\caption{{\normalsize Results from OLS Estimation}}\\
```

That's pretty much all that is needed. However, the code becomes much more readable if you make the most common cell format the default:

```
\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
```

and then omit every `\multicolumn{1}{c}`.

Comment: Dear Dan,thank you very much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to moving the `\small` instruction *outside* the `\longtable` environment and *not overusing* the `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` instruction, you should consider using (i) the `dcolumn` package to align the columns of numeric data on the respective decimal markers and (ii) the `booktabs` package to produce better-looking horizontal lines in the table's header and footer zones. Once you start using the rule-drawing commands of this package, you'll never need to use vertical rules in a table again. :-)

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable,dcolumn,booktabs}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in]{geometry} % choose page margins as needed for your document
\newcolumntype{d}{D..{2.6}}        % column type: decimal-aligned
\newcommand{\mcc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % shortcut command

\begin{document}
{\small % \small is a switch, not an environment
\begin{longtable}{@{}l *{6}{d} @{}}
\caption{Results from OLS Estimation} \label{tab:OLSresults}\\

\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Males} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Females} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
& \mcc{(1)} & \mcc{(2)} & \mcc{(3)} & \mcc{(4)} & \mcc{(5)} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{(6)} \\
& \mcc{OLS-NGive} & \mcc{OLS-GGive} & \mcc{OLS-GRec} & \mcc{OLS-NGive} & \mcc{OLS-GGive} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{OLS-GRec} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{7}{@{}l@{}}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- Continued} \\ 
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Males} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Females} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
& \mcc{(1)} & \mcc{(2)} & \mcc{(3)} & \mcc{(4)} & \mcc{(5)} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{(6)} \\
& \mcc{OLS-NGive} & \mcc{OLS-GGive} & \mcc{OLS-GRec} & \mcc{OLS-NGive} & \mcc{OLS-GGive} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{OLS-GRec} \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{7}{r@{}}{Continued on next page} \\ 
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

Log wage & 0.2754** & 0.1301* & -0.1309** & 0.3629** & 0.2700** & -0.0815+ \\
          & (0.0814) & (0.0613) & (0.0494) & (0.0803) & (0.0625) & (0.0473) \\
Age   & 0.0128 & 0.0589 & 0.0432 & 0.0879 & 0.0226 & -0.0691 \\
          & (0.0880) & (0.0740) & (0.0473) & (0.0812) & (0.0600) & (0.0520) \\
Age sq & 0.0001 & -0.0004 & -0.0005 & -0.0007 & -0.0002 & 0.0005 \\
          & (0.0008) & (0.0006) & (0.0004) & (0.0007) & (0.0005) & (0.0005) \\
Educ  & 0.0174 & -0.0721 & -0.1064** & -0.1381 & -0.2056* & -0.0770** \\
          & (0.0609) & (0.0543) & (0.0245) & (0.0902) & (0.0848) & (0.0258) \\
Educ sq & 0.0003 & 0.0051* & 0.0055** & 0.0051 & 0.0095** & 0.0047** \\
          & (0.0026) & (0.0022) & (0.0013) & (0.0036) & (0.0032) & (0.0013) \\
Non-labor inc & 0.0027* & 0.0024* & -0.0003 & 0.0010 & 0.0013+ & 0.0002 \\
          & (0.0012) & (0.0010) & (0.0005) & (0.0008) & (0.0007) & (0.0004) \\
HH wealth & 0.0079 & 0.0160* & 0.0077 & 0.0022 & 0.0004 & -0.0012 \\
          & (0.0093) & (0.0068) & (0.0050) & (0.0043) & (0.0038) & (0.0019) \\
Nwhite & 0.9998** & 0.7522** & -0.2394** & 0.6197** & 0.4897** & -0.1332* \\
          & (0.1271) & (0.1149) & (0.0470) & (0.1142) & (0.0968) & (0.0572) \\
Hisp  & 0.6440** & 0.4753** & -0.1572** & 0.6450** & 0.6302** & -0.0371 \\
          & (0.1728) & (0.1607) & (0.0559) & (0.1904) & (0.1719) & (0.0701) \\
Married & -0.3104* & -0.3796** & -0.0801 & 0.2232* & -0.0784 & -0.3247** \\
          & (0.1472) & (0.1296) & (0.0853) & (0.1107) & (0.0858) & (0.0662) \\
Poor health & -0.0069 & 0.0406 & 0.0520 & -0.0710 & 0.0845 & 0.1645** \\
          & (0.1004) & (0.0801) & (0.0576) & (0.1052) & (0.0844) & (0.0590) \\
Children (0--5) & -0.1143 & -0.0376 & 0.0835 & 0.0154 & -0.0310 & -0.0397 \\
          & (0.1293) & (0.0927) & (0.0825) & (0.1083) & (0.0919) & (0.0561) \\
Children (6--18) & -0.1533* & -0.0320 & 0.1166** & -0.1228+ & -0.0113 & 0.1015* \\
          & (0.0675) & (0.0513) & (0.0400) & (0.0652) & (0.0487) & (0.0407) \\
N of own sis & -0.0388 & -0.0311 & 0.0098 & 0.0632* & -0.0008 & -0.0510** \\
          & (0.0281) & (0.0221) & (0.0152) & (0.0250) & (0.0208) & (0.0121) \\
N of own bro & 0.0514+ & 0.0228 & -0.0270+ & 0.0099 & -0.0128 & -0.0206 \\
          & (0.0268) & (0.0223) & (0.0138) & (0.0271) & (0.0224) & (0.0138) \\
N of spouse sis & 0.0115 & -0.0176 & -0.0275* & -0.0105 & 0.0042 & 0.0197 \\
          & (0.0270) & (0.0221) & (0.0136) & (0.0277) & (0.0226) & (0.0146) \\
N of spouse bro & 0.0052 & 0.0026 & 0.0002 & 0.0247 & 0.0168 & -0.0091 \\
          & (0.0311) & (0.0252) & (0.0159) & (0.0292) & (0.0246) & (0.0141) \\
N of parents & 0.2854** & 0.3605** & 0.0725* & 0.2085** & 0.2918** & 0.0849* \\
          & (0.0621) & (0.0469) & (0.0367) & (0.0625) & (0.0466) & (0.0367) \\
Mothers/parents & 0.2108+ & 0.2918** & 0.0499 & 0.2833* & 0.3428** & 0.0369 \\
          & (0.1190) & (0.0862) & (0.0772) & (0.1119) & (0.0799) & (0.0753) \\
Parents' age & -0.0137* & -0.0052 & 0.0076* & -0.0088 & 0.0022 & 0.0096* \\
          & (0.0067) & (0.0056) & (0.0036) & (0.0068) & (0.0055) & (0.0038) \\
Parents' educ & -0.0619** & -0.0140 & 0.0437** & -0.0506** & -0.0064 & 0.0444** \\
          & (0.0168) & (0.0139) & (0.0080) & (0.0158) & (0.0128) & (0.0083) \\
At least one parent   & 0.2178* & 0.3229** & 0.1104+ & 0.1486+ & 0.2837** & 0.1480** \\
\ \ \ single  & (0.0945) & (0.0706) & (0.0575) & (0.0873) & (0.0668) & (0.0524) \\
Needs care & 0.0447 & -0.0174 & -0.0586 & 0.0251 & 0.0068 & -0.0297 \\
          & (0.0892) & (0.0735) & (0.0459) & (0.0857) & (0.0694) & (0.0466) \\
Cannot be & 0.0740 & 0.1054 & 0.0193 & -0.0068 & -0.0029 & 0.0188 \\
\ \ \ left alone & (0.0981) & (0.0797) & (0.0511) & (0.0913) & (0.0733) & (0.0499) \\
Homeowner & -0.0436 & 0.0117 & 0.0492 & 0.0185 & 0.0415 & 0.0276 \\
          & (0.0957) & (0.0814) & (0.0448) & (0.0897) & (0.0745) & (0.0461) \\
Poorer & 0.8224** & 0.7197** & -0.1096* & 0.8435** & 0.6969** & -0.1552** \\
          & (0.0828) & (0.0671) & (0.0434) & (0.0798) & (0.0668) & (0.0397) \\
Richer & -0.9860** & -0.4509** & 0.5021** & -1.0081** & -0.4896** & 0.4862** \\
          & (0.0851) & (0.0636) & (0.0525) & (0.0805) & (0.0590) & (0.0495) \\
\midrule
Observations & \mcc{11,387} & \mcc{11,387} & \mcc{11,387} & \mcc{13,275} & \mcc{13,275} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{13,275} \\
R-squared & 0.0956 & 0.0875 & 0.0570 & 0.0929 & 0.0819 & 0.0555 \\
\end{longtable}
} % end of scope of \small instruction
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Mico, thank you very much. All the answers were really helpful. And I now have it working. I see the point in making the table simpler. My problem with this is that to create it I have used excel2latex macro, and the resulting massive use of multicolumn is from there. For me it is really crucial to get the process as automatic as possible because I often need to redo the tables many times before the publication. I guess I would have to look for a different way of transferring results from STATA to Latex. If you have a suggestion, I would really appreciate this.